# Visual Studio 2017 SPA Aurelia template: Where is aurelia.json?

Tags: single-page-application, aurelia, asp.net-core-2.0

I used the Visual Studio 2017 (ASP.NET Core 2.0) SPA Aurelia template to create a new solution, but I am missing the aurelia.json file. Why doesn't it get created? It is also not clear where the "resources" folder has to be created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `aurelia.json` file does not get created because it is needed by the Aurelia CLI build tool only. Since the VS template uses Webpack as a build tool, `aurelia.json` is unnecessary - you configure your build process by tweaking the Webpack configuration files.

About the `resources` folder, I guess that you refer to the one that is created by the Aurelia CLI `au new` command, that is, the one in which you generally store your reusable components and similar things. If that is the case, technically, it shouldn't matter where it is as long as you properly configure your imports, such as `.feature('resources')`, in your `main.ts` (or `boot.ts` as it is called when created by the VS template) - though for the sake of making it easy to oversee your project structure, I suggest you sticking to the structure that is created by the `au new` CLI command, and create your `resources` folder directly inside the `ClientApp` folder.

Comment: I have a "resources/elements/loading-indicator.ts" inside "ClientApp" but the loading-indicator cannot be used/found. Inside "resources" I have an "index.ts" with

export function configure(config: any) {
    config.globalResources(['./elements/loading-indicator']);
}

Am I missing something?

Comment: Do you have a `.feature('resources')` call on the `aurelia.use` chain in your main/boot.ts file?

Comment: When I do so, I am getting "Unable to find module with ID: resources/index
    at WebpackLoader.<anonymous>" although I do have the index.ts/js (I tried both) file there.

Comment: That's odd. I suggest you post a separate question about it, it's going to be hard to track the issue down in the comment section.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46593108/aurelia-with-asp-net-core-2-0-unable-to-find-module-with-id-resources-index