# Aurelia with ASP.NET Core 2.0: Unable to find module with ID: resources/index

Tags: webpack, aurelia, asp.net-core-2.0

I created a Visual Studio 2017 ASP.NET Core 2.0 solution by using the SPA Aurelia template. Everything works fine so far but I don't get the configuration (in "boot.ts") to find my "resources/elements" folder (or it's index.ts):

```
export function configure(aurelia: Aurelia) {
    aurelia.use
        .standardConfiguration()
        .feature(PLATFORM.moduleName('resources'));
```

> "Unable to find module with ID: resources/index
>   at WebpackLoader. (aurelia-loader-webpack.js:187)"

The index.ts:

```
import { FrameworkConfiguration } from 'aurelia-framework';

export function configure(config: FrameworkConfiguration) {
    config.globalResources(['./elements/loading-indicator']);
}
```

The solution structure:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had to change

```
.feature(PLATFORM.moduleName('resources'));
```

to

```
.feature(PLATFORM.moduleName('resources/index'));
```

(https://github.com/aurelia/webpack-plugin/issues/108)

and

```
import { FrameworkConfiguration } from 'aurelia-framework';

export function configure(config: FrameworkConfiguration) {
    config.globalResources([
        './elements/loading-indicator'
    ]);
}
```

to

```
import { FrameworkConfiguration, PLATFORM } from 'aurelia-framework';

export function configure(config: FrameworkConfiguration) {
    config.globalResources([
        PLATFORM.moduleName('./elements/loading-indicator')
    ]);
}
```

and also

```
@noView([ 'nprogress/nprogress.css' ])
export class LoadingIndicator {
...
}
```

to

```
@noView([ PLATFORM.moduleName('nprogress/nprogress.css') ])
export class LoadingIndicator {
...
}
```

;)